# Exercise about finding group isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

So, i've just learned about groups homomorphisms and isomorphisms. I know that an homormorphism betweet two groups is a function such that

$$\phi(a\square b) = \phi(a)\star \phi(b)$$

And when the homomosphism is bijective, then we have an isomorphism betweet the two groups.

The problem is that the exercise asks me to tell is these groups are isomorphic:

$$(\Bbb Z_6, +),  (\Bbb Z_7^*,.)$$

In this case, I'm looking at the groups:

$$(\Bbb Z_6, +) = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}, (\Bbb Z_7^*,.) = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$

However, there's no explanation of which is the homomorphism that I have to check, so I'm lost.

The same for these two groups: 
$$(\Bbb Z_2 \times\Bbb Z_2), \Bbb Z_4$$

Could somebody help me?

Comment: It is not asking you to check if a specific thing is an isomorphism. It is asking  you if there is some isomorphism. So either you need to construct one, or you need to argue that there is none.

Comment: hint:  if $\phi$ is a group homomorphism from G $\rightarrow$ H, and G is the cyclic group generated by some element g, then $\phi$ is completely determined by $\phi(g)$ (you should persuade yourself that this is true!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Any* homomorphism $\phi$ out of $\Bbb Z_6$ is totally dictated by $\phi(1)$, since:

$\phi(n) = n\cdot \phi(1) = \phi(1+1+\cdots+1)$ ($n$ times)

$= \phi(1) \ast \phi(1) \ast \cdots \ast \phi(1) = \phi(1)^n$ (since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, where $\ast$ is the operation in the target group).

Now for $\phi: \Bbb Z_6 \to (\Bbb Z_7)^{\times}$, this gives us $6$ choices for $\phi(1)$ (note the operation in the latter group is *multiplication* mod $7$).

If $\phi(1) = 1$, then $\phi(n) = 1$, for all $n \in \Bbb Z_6$, this is the trivial homomorphism, which is definitely *not* bijective.

This leaves us with $5$ other choices.

If $\phi(1) = -1 = 6$, we have $\phi(2) = \phi( 1+ 1) = \phi(1)\phi(1) = 6\cdot 6 = 1$ (since $36 = 1$ (mod $7$)).

This implies $\phi(4) = \phi(2 + 2) = \phi(2)\phi(2) = 1\cdot 1 = 1$, so this homomorphism is not injective either ($2 \neq 4$ in $\Bbb Z_6$, but $\phi(2) = \phi (4)$).

Down to $4$ possible choices, now.

If $\phi(1) = 2$, we have $\phi(2) = \phi(1+1) = \phi(1)\phi(1) = 2\cdot 2 = 4$. Thus $\phi(3) = \phi(2 + 1) = \phi(2)\phi(1) = 4\cdot 2 = 1$, so $\phi$ sends $0 \to 1$ and $3 \to 1$, and again it is not injective.

A similar argument shows $\phi(1) = 4$ is also not injective (the details of which I leave to you).

So let's examine $\phi(1) = 3$ (the case $\phi(1) = 5$ is similar):

$\phi(0) = 1\\ \phi(1) = 3\\ \phi(2) = 3\cdot 3 = 2\\ \phi(3) = 3\cdot 3\cdot 3 = 2\cdot 3 = 6\\ \phi(4) = 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3 = 6  \cdot 3 = 4\\ \phi(5) = 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3 = 4\cdot 3 = 5$

This is clearly a bijection, and we have (by the way we define $\phi$) that:

$\phi(k+m) = \phi((k+m)\cdot 1) = [\phi(1)]^{k+m} = \phi(1)^k\phi(1)^m = \phi(k\cdot 1)\phi(m\cdot 1) = \phi(k)\phi(m)$,

so it is an homomorphism, as well.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks by your time <3

Answer (score 1):

For $\Bbb{Z}_6$ and $\Bbb{Z}_7^*$, a hint: both are cyclic; can you use this to construct an isomorphism?

For groups of very small orders, you could also look at their multiplication table and see if you can identify one element with another.

The easiest way to see that two groups are not isomorphic is to find a group property that  one group has and the other doesn't have. Some of properties that are preserved by homomorphisms are the order of the groups, whether they are cyclic, whether they are abelian, and how many elements of a certain order they have.

Comment: Why both groups being cyclic ables me to constructo an isomorphism? Is there a theorem about it? Could you help me? Thanks <3

Comment: I think I'm missing something big.

Comment: You can construct a homomorphism by sending the generator of one group to the generator of the other group. If $G$ and $H$ are cyclic, then $G = \langle x \rangle$ and $H=\langle y \rangle$ for some elements. Suppose $G$ and $H$ have the same order and try verifying that the map $\varphi : G \to H$ defined by $\varphi(x^k)=y^k$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Guerlando OCs: It is well known theorem that,"Two cyclic groups of same order are isomorphic" you can prove it

Comment: @Chiranjeev: it might not be well known to someone who's taking their first algebra course; I know my teacher wouldn't have let me just use that in my homework without proving it. In fact, in my course it was a homework problem. It's also a good problem to become comfortable with the definition and properties of homomorphisms (the finite case is not too hard).

Comment: if you don't know ,you can prove it by hint of ColdNumber

Comment: If you are new, your approach should be finding order of element and then using the property of homomorphism try to relate elements.

Comment: @Chiranjeev which property? Would be nice if you could help me in an answer :)

Comment: For the proof of the homomorphism from generator to generator you should use the property that $\varphi(x^k)=(\varphi(x))^k$. (My book has it as a theorem and proves it by induction.)